# What is happening to my internet connection? I can Ping, query Dns but i cant view webpage?

Tags: home-networking, internet-connection

I'm experiencing a weird problem that I would like to understand.

My DSL connection won't allow me to visit website.
I can't access them using IP address either,
but I can still ping 8.8.8.8
and www.google.ca (So DNS query works, I cleared my cache to be sure)
On top of that I have a VoIP ATA adapter and the phone still works.

From what I know of TCP/IP the problem seems to be in TCP since UDP and ICMP still seems to work.
This is the same with every device I try on my network wired or wireless.
Tried 2 different laptops, 1 running Lubuntu and 1 running Windows 8 and multiple IOS device

Has anyone ever seen a problem like this?

Comment: sounds like your router is to blame, try a factory reset, failing that tech support at your isp.

Comment: Did both. Waiting on a call back from my ISP. I do feel it probably is the router but i dont know how to check

Comment: Can you plug the outside line directly into your pc?

Comment: No my modem is built in with the router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out my problem was with the MTU.

When I changed IP address I had to lower the MTU because one of the router is misbehaving